# Delete file if has no records in line number 4, PYTHON

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a set of ".tab" extension files which are generated from a tool in bioinformatics, the tool is working on a defense system found in bacterias which is called BREX.
The file format of the file looks like this :

```
#                                                                            --- full sequence --- -------------- this domain -------------   hmm coord   ali coord   env coord
# target name        accession   tlen query name           accession   qlen   E-value  score  bias   #  of  c-Evalue  i-Evalue  score  bias  from    to  from    to  from    to  acc description of target
#------------------- ---------- ----- -------------------- ---------- ----- --------- ------ ----- --- --- --------- --------- ------ ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ---------------------
#
# Program:         hmmsearch
```

In this case the file has no records because at line number 4 we do not have records. If the file would have had records would not have been empty at the fourth line. My task is to delete such files that do not have records, these "empty" files (which are not compitely empty because they have something written on) are  in the folder that I have the set of all ".tab" files. For this task I try to execute this piece of code :

```
def deleteEmptyFiles (brexType):
    BREXFolder = "./"
    allfiles = os.listdir(BREXFolder)
    allBREXfiles = []
    for x in allfiles:
        if x.endswith("%s.tab" %brexType):
            allBREXfiles.append(x)
    for x in allBREXfiles:
        with open(x,"r") as f:
                for line in f:
                    lineNo = 1
                    while lineNo < 5:
                        lineNo +=1
                    i=1
                    for i in range(lineNo):
                        if not line.strip('#'):
                            os.remove(x)
                            print("File %s is removed! It has no records." %x)
```

My logic is to find out is line no.4 has records or not. If not, I want to delete the file. I execute the program but it does nothing.
Please help!

Comment: Since these files must be pretty small in size compared to the ones with a record, can't you just check the size of each file and delete those that match an "empty" file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact structure of your file, but I managed to do something like this:

```
import os

def deleteEmptyFiles():
    BREXFolder = "./"
    for fh in os.listdir(BREXFolder):
        if fh.endswith('.tab'):
            opened_file = open(os.path.join(BREXFolder, fh), 'r')
            data = [line.strip() for line in opened_file]
            if data[3] == '#':
                opened_file.close()
                print(f'Deleted file {fh}')
                os.remove(fh)
```

There is even more efficent way. Insted of reading the whole file, you can just iterate through it, and compare line number and it's data. Here you go:

```
import os

def deleteEmptyFiles():
    BREXFolder = "./"
    for fh in os.listdir(BREXFolder):
        if fh.endswith('.tab'):
            opened_file = open(os.path.join(BREXFolder, fh), 'r')
            for i, line in enumerate(opened_file, 1):
                if i == 4 and line.strip() == '#':
                    opened_file.close()
                    print(f'Removed file {fh}')
                    os.remove(fh)
                    break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    deleteEmptyFiles()
```